# Store key file as embedded resource (how unsafe is it?)

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, reverse-engineering

If I have a stored key file used to decrypt the encrypted input coming into my application, and I store that key file as an embedded resource so that it is embedded in the assembly when deploying, how difficult would it be for someone to reverse engineer the application and retrieve the key file?

Also, the application is deployed through ClickOnce "Online only" mode which I imagine would also make it more difficult to reverse engineer? (I'm not exactly sure of the workings of ClickOnce but I wasn't able to find the dll's/assemblies on my local machine after running the application in online only mode...).

**Update:**
As Ralf essentially answered the main question below in his comment (*answer: it's not really safe at all*), here's some more information so that you knowledgeable people can possibly suggest a better security model.

- The encryption will be used to encrypt the login password for my application, to be used in a SSO setup (the user will first sign on to a different system and then by clicking a link will be able to directly open my application without having to enter in their login details).
- The encrypted data will be sent as a base-64 string URL parameter in the link that will launch the my click-once application.
- I will also be developing the application that will create the encrypted data for the URL parameter (*clarification*: not the first application the user will sign in to for the SSO, I will only be creating a small tool to convert the plain text password into an encrypted base64 string).
- It's only an internal application so bullet proof security isn't essential and ease of deployment is more important, but it'd be nice to know what the best practices and different options that are available.

Comment: Go to the Taskmanager. Find your running process. Find the open path menuitem to open the folder where your programm is. Use any available  Resource Hacker tool and you will get to the embedded resources and therefore the key. If you know that there should be a key in the resources its likely not more than a few seconds work to get it.

Comment: It is just as safe as keeping your apartment's door key under the potted plant.

Comment: Where is the encrypted data coming from?

Comment: Ok, so not really safe at all.  Security through obscurity at best.  I like @HansPassant's example.  Not very secure, but probably enough to keep honest people honest.

Comment: @NeilSmithline The data is the login password being passed to the click once application as a URL parameter (in the link to launch the application).  It's just an internal application and security is not actually that important, more than anything we just didn't want to send the password in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

Whether in clear text or encrypted, you don't want to store the password. When you get a password, all you should do is pass it to your server app where you compare it against the salted hash of the password you have in the DB. Even if you don't think security is that important, you need to take care with the password because people frequently reuse passwords across different systems. I know they shouldn't but they do.

If you want to implement a single sign on (SSO), create a sign on token on the server side and pass it back to the client, either encrypted or signed ([HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is a good choice for signing). This is an unforgeable token because you need to know the encryption key or shared secret for the HMAC and that data is only known on your servers. So you have your SSO and all data involving the SSO is managed on servers so there's no data leakage or chance of spoofing.

Comment: I can't use a sign on token because I can't change the calling application - all I can do is provide the tool for them to encrypt the password which they will send as part of the URL parameters to my application.  However, the passwords will not be user-generated, so in a way they are somewhat similar to tokens.

Comment: If you can't change the client then I guess you're rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the aplication can be launched, the files have to be somewhere on the computer. You just have to know where to look. The reverse-engineering may be ugly but it is always possible. The computer has to be able to understand what he is supposed to do so you only have to extraxt the information one is looking for. Therefore the security of your application should never depend on the difficulty of reverse-engineering! I believe that a secure application should be open-source anyways.

You propably need a diffent security model. The important thing here is that you know against what you want to protect the data. If you simply want that you know the data is sent by the server and not somebody else (man in the middle attack) you could use digital signatures instead.
If you do not want anybody to read any data sent between server and client you should use some sort of ssl implementation to create an encrypted channel. Then you only need to watch out that the public key of the server is not altered on the client. This may be done by an certificate of an official CA but unfortunately those are usualy not for free.

Comment: Public CA's are only for when you only control one side of the communication. If you control both the client and the server you don't need a public CA, just make a private CA and install your CA's certificate in your application, you can then make all the certificates you want for any services that your application talks to and it can verify them against the hardcoded CA's certificate built in to the app.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain would a private CA certificate installed into my application be more secure than a regular key file?  If someone reverse-engineered the application would they be able to retrieve the hardcoded CA certificate?

Comment: @JPProgrammer yes they could, but they could not generate new valid certificates (Which they would need to do if they were going to do a MITM attack) from only the CA certificate, they also would need the private key which you would have on your internal company servers only. Its the same as a public CA, you have all of their certificates on your machine too, it is just the only thing you can do with them is verify signed certificates.

Comment: I have to add here, that the verification of private certificates can be done by the server only. Since the application is deliverd through the network there is no security against a man in the middle attack without a 3rd party.